# Formik form with arrayHelper - onchange event. Performance slowdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, debouncing

I'm working with formik library and displaying lot of fields with formik arrayHelper but I faced with rly big performance slowdown while typing.

I changed onChange event to modify my objects array - I using arrayHelper to change object because I have to add action type for each change:

```
 <FastField component={TextareaComponent}
            autoFocus={added && index === questions.length - 1}
            placeholder="Question"
            name={`questions.${index}.question`}
            id={`questions.${index}.question`}
            rows={3}
            onFocus={e => scrollOnFocus(e)}
            onChange={e =>
                      questionHelper.replace(index, {
                      ...question,
                      question: e.target.value,
                      action: question.id ? 'update' : 'create'
                                                   })
 }/>
```

The problem is that the whole form rerendering lot of times when I just type 1 letter.

I changed from Field to FastField component and add _.debounce for validation and it helps a little bit to improve performance but issue it's still exist.

Comment: Are you able to recreate issue in codesandbox or stackblitz

Comment: Already fixed. I moved all my logic for array changing with action field to submit.